Group by LINQ for multiple columns
I have a datable from SP which has Category, Subcategory and Message. For one Category there is multiple subcategories and for one subcategory there is multiple message texts. So in Get services I need to send these category in array format in an object.



CategoryName
SubCategoryName
MessageText




Framing
Face Covered
Child's face can not be clearly seen


Framing
Face Covered
food detected


Lighting
Incorrect lighting
Poor lighting detected


Lighting
Incorrect lighting
Not recommended


Lighting
Too dark
Sun behind the Child detected



I'm using asp.net core 8 application. I have two model class
So in existing service I need to add these response details, so created one private method in DAL Layer.
I'm trying to add groupby for categoryname and subactegoryname but I'm getting some error**"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<Char>>' to 'String'"** .
The Code which I written;
private List<ARMCategory> CategoryDetailsCUP(DataSet mediaReviewDetails)
{
    List<ARMCategory> ARMCategory = new List<ARMCategory>();
    if (mediaReviewDetails != null)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in mediaReviewDetails.Tables[2].Rows)
        {
            List<ARMSubCategory> results2 = ARMCategory
            .GroupBy(p => new { p.CategoryName, p.SubCategoryNames },
                     (k, c) => new ARMCategory()
                     {
                         CategoryName = k.CategoryName,
                         SubCategoryNames = c.Select(cs => cs.SubCategoryNames.ToList()),
                         MessageTexts = c.Select(cs => cs.MessageTexts.ToList())
                     }
                    ).ToList();
            return ARMCategory;
        }
    }
    //return result2;
}


For example the output I needed,
For Category Framing we have a Facecovered Subcategory so it needs to map under category framing and for Subcategory facecovered we have multiple MessageText so these texts should map under respective subcategory. Like these for each Category need to map respective subcategory and message text.
So need code in C#

Your .ToList() calls are happening on your SubCategoryNames and MessageTexts properties, rather than the collections of those properties. Move the ) from the end of those lines to in front of the .ToList().

Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's difficult to understand what format your data is coming from. You say it's in the data table, and your code is iterating over the data table's rows, but you don't do anything with dataRow. Your query is pulling from an empty list that you created, which is also what you return. Please update your question to make it clear what the expected shape of your input and output are.

please provide class structure

I'm fetching the details which I mentioned in the table from the SP where it's table index is 2, and dbconnection and other objects are there in main function. So  in private function need to map the details from the table index 2 and call this function in main method. Need to return the results for each category retrive subcategory and message texts mapped to that Subcategory. If there any other way possible pls suggest. I'm new bie don't know much abuot it.

This is the class structure
public class ARMCategory
{
public string CategoryName 

public string SubCategoryNames

public string MessageTexts

}
public class ARMSubCategory
{
public string CategoryName
public List SubCategoryName
 public List<string> MessageTexts 
 public List<int> ActionTypeCode

}
There is actiontypecode which is int value 55 will be mapped to each messagetexts.

Please, read @StriplingWarrior comment. you are not linking ANY data from DataRow,  also please proved what expected output you want

The Expected Output somewhat like this:
"APIDetails": {"category": [{"categoryName": "Framing","armSubCategories": [{"subCategoryName": "Face Covered","armValidationMessage": [{"messageText": "Child's face can not be clearly seen","actionType": 55 }, "messageText": "Child's face can not be clearly seen","actionType": 55}], "subCategoryName": "Face Covered","armValidationMessage": [{"messageText": "Child's face can not be clearly seen","actionType": 55},}]}]}

Please do not add comments to when clarity is requested, please edit your question with the details.

ok. i try to create an example to point you to error.

you are not using any data, coming-in in to function.
because you did not provided class structure, i would assume myself what structure new ARMCategory class should be.
you have ARMCategories.GroupBy  (where SubCategoryName is a string) and at
the same time you have (k, c) => new ARMCategory() -where SubCategoryName is a List

so you have multiple options:

can aggredate list in to one string
create a New class where subCategory would be a list

void Main()
{
    List<ARMCategory> ARMCategories = new List<ARMCategory>(){
        new ARMCategory() { CategoryName = "Framing", SubCategoryName = "Face Covered", MessageText = "Child's face can not be clearly seen" },
        new ARMCategory() { CategoryName = "Framing", SubCategoryName = "Face Covered", MessageText = "food detected" },
        new ARMCategory() { CategoryName = "Lighting",SubCategoryName = "Incorrect lighting", MessageText = "Poor lighting detected" },
        new ARMCategory() { CategoryName = "Lighting",SubCategoryName = "Incorrect lighting", MessageText = "Not recommended" },
        new ARMCategory() { CategoryName = "Lighting",SubCategoryName = "Too dark", MessageText = "Sun behind the Child detected"}
    };
    var results2 = ARMCategories
                    .GroupBy(p => new { p.CategoryName, p.SubCategoryName },
                             (k, c) => new NEW_Class_Structure
                             {
                                 CategoryName = k.CategoryName,
                                 SubCategoryNames = c.Select(s => s.SubCategoryName).ToList(),//.Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a}, {b}"),
                                 MessageTexts = c.Select(cs => cs.MessageText).ToList()
                             }
                            ).ToList().Dump();


}

public class ARMCategory{
    public string CategoryName{get;set;}
    public string SubCategoryName {get;set;}
    public string MessageText {get;set;}
}

public class NEW_Class_Structure
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<string> SubCategoryNames { get; set; }
    public List<string> MessageTexts { get; set; }
}




UPDATE:
since you provided desired output (broken json too) in original question comments:
{
    "APIDetails": {
        "category": [
            {
                "categoryName": "Framing",
                "armSubCategories": [
                    {
                        "subCategoryName": "Face Covered",
                        "armValidationMessage": [
                            {
                                "messageText": "Child's face can not be clearly seen",
                                "actionType": 55
                            },
                            {
                                "messageText": "Child's face can not be clearly seen",
                                "actionType": 55
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "subCategoryName": "Face Covered",
                        "armValidationMessage": [
                            {
                                "messageText": "Child's face can not be clearly seen",
                                "actionType": 55
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

I updated example to match result you expecting.
P.S. no clue where action type coming from - hardcoded
since SubCategory is list of same key - taking first or default.
also, modified additional class for message and action
void Main()
{
    List<ARMCategory> ARMCategories = new List<ARMCategory>(){
        new ARMCategory() { CategoryName = "Framing", SubCategoryName = "Face Covered", MessageText = "Child's face can not be clearly seen" },
        new ARMCategory() { CategoryName = "Framing", SubCategoryName = "Face Covered", MessageText = "food detected" },
        new ARMCategory() { CategoryName = "Lighting",SubCategoryName = "Incorrect lighting", MessageText = "Poor lighting detected" },
        new ARMCategory() { CategoryName = "Lighting",SubCategoryName = "Incorrect lighting", MessageText = "Not recommended" },
        new ARMCategory() { CategoryName = "Lighting",SubCategoryName = "Too dark", MessageText = "Sun behind the Child detected"}
    };
    var results2 = ARMCategories
                    .GroupBy(p => new { p.CategoryName, p.SubCategoryName },
                             (k, c) => new NEW_Class_Structure
                             {
                                 CategoryName = k.CategoryName,
                                 SubCategoryName = c.Select(s => s.SubCategoryName).FirstOrDefault(),//.Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a}, {b}"),
                                 armValidationMessage = c.Select(cs => new ValidationMessage() { MessageText = cs.MessageText, actionType = 55}).ToList()
                             }
                            ).ToList().Dump();
}

public class ARMCategory
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
}

public class NEW_Class_Structure
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<ValidationMessage> armValidationMessage { get; set; }

    public NEW_Class_Structure() {
        armValidationMessage = new List<ValidationMessage>();
    }
}

public class ValidationMessage{
    public string MessageText {get;set;}
    public int actionType {get;set;}
}


